# Redirect 'Switch to Salesforce Classic' Link to VF Page

Tags: lightning, classic

Can anyone suggest a way to redirect Salesforce Lightning's 'Switch to Salesforce' link? I can't seem to capture the data around the moment the switch happens.

I tried using a simple trigger (similar to the the one below) to see if it fires when the user record changes, but it doesn't. I also tried using a Flow/Process builder combination. That didn't work either. Can anyone suggest a direction to research?

```
trigger SwitchLink on User(before update, after update){

    for(User u : trigger.new){
        system.debug(u.UserPreferencesLightningExperiencePreferred);
        system.debug(u.id);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I wish I had an answer. I'm curious to know the use case.

Comment: When a user chooses to switch to classic, i want them to encounter a feedback screen so that I can capture their reason why.

Comment: That's a neat idea, I hope you figure it out. Ill be watching this post :)